# Rails Select_tag/Select_year to select integers/years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails select_tag needs to select from the years 2013-2017 which are stored into the DB as integers. I've been looking into `select_year` from [This ruby on rails Guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year) but am still having a little trouble with it. The select_tag is for the `:year` attribute.

How can I make this specific select?? I also want to `include_blank => "-------"` in the select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
select_year(Date.today, {start_year: 2006, end_year: 2007}, name: 'collection[year]', include_blank: true )
```

```
"<select id="date_year" include_blank="true" name="collection[year]"><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2007">2007</option></select>"
```

You can embed your html option as `id` and other simply divide them `{}`

look this `select_year(date, options = {}, html_options = {})`

first argument is `Date.today`

 next is `start_year: 2006, end_year: 2007`

 last html_options `name: 'collection[year]', include_blank: true`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, start_year: 2013, end_year: 2017, include_blank: true) %>
```

should be fine except you get blank empty select instead of -------.

Comment: That's not setting the model's year attribute though. If you were to inspect element for the Select in the browser, you'd see the name for that Select is `name="date[year]"` instead of `name="collection[year]"` - Collection is the model in this case

Comment: You  didn't write anything about `collection` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is not correct. The `include_blank` options is *not* an `html_option`, and must be specified along with the `start_year` and `end_year` options, as follows:

```
select_year(Date.today, {start_year: 2006, end_year: 2007, include_blank: true}, name: 'collection[year]')
```